# How I can get object from another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, shopping-cart

I'm trying to do a Shopping cart with HTML and JS. So I'm using (https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/08/shopping-cart-html5-web-storage/).
In my function save(), I have,

```
`function save(id, title, price) {
    // var button = document.getElementById('button');
    // button.onclick=function(){
        // var test = localStorage.setItem('test', id);
        window.location.href='/panier'
        var obj = {
            title: title,
            price: price
        };
        localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(obj));
         var test = localStorage.getItem(id);
        var getObject = JSON.parse(test);
        console.log(getObject.title);
        console.log(getObject.price);
}`
```

so to get "title for example I don't have problem in my function save(), but in my function doShowAll(),

```
function CheckBrowser() {
    if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        // We can use localStorage object to store data.
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function doShowAll() {
    if (CheckBrowser()) {
        var key = "";
        var id = localStorage.getItem(id);
        var list = "<tr><th>Item</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n";
        var i = 0;
        //For a more advanced feature, you can set a cap on max items in the cart.
        for (i = 0; i <= localStorage.length-1; i++) {
            key = localStorage.key(i);
            list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>\n<td>"
                    + localStorage.getItem(key) + "</td></tr>\n";
        }
        //If no item exists in the cart.
        if (list == "<tr><th>Item</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n") {
            list += "<tr><td><i>empty</i></td>\n<td><i>empty</i></td></tr>\n";
        }
        //Bind the data to HTML table.
        //You can use jQuery, too.
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = list;
    } else {
        alert('Cannot save shopping list as your browser does not support HTML 5');
    }
}
```

I can't to get my object.
I have tried:

```
if (CheckBrowser()) {
            var key = "";
            var id = localStorage.getItem(id);
            var getObject = JSON.parse(test);
    }
            var list = "<tr><th>Item</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n";
            var i = 0;
            //For a more advanced feature, you can set a cap on max items in the cart.
            for (i = 0; i <= localStorage.length-1; i++) {
                key = localStorage.key(i);
                list += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>\n<td>" + getObject.title
                        + localStorage.getItem(key) + "</td></tr>\n";
            }
```

but when I add something else than key or localStorage.getItem(key) in "list +=" nothing is displayed in my html view.

**So I just Want to display data from my object in the PHP array in doShowAll() function.**
Hoping to have clear and wainting a reply. Thank you

Comment: `var getObject = JSON.parse(test);` ... what is `test`? - edit: oh, it's a variable inside another function - no, you can't peek into a function like that ... and also `var id = localStorage.getItem(id);` can never work, since `id` is undefined when it's passed to `getItem`

Comment: so, you call `save` with an `id` ... just use that same variable or constant or whatever you use (you don't show how you call save so I'm guessing) and use that to `localStorage.getItem`